# VBA Coding Issues with both Pivot Table and Power Chart

Tags: excel

I’m creating a Pivot Table and Power Chart in Excel 2016. I’m having issues with the Power Chart portion. Could someone assist with me locating the “source data” in VBA for Pivot Table and Power Chart macro?

I’m confused because VBA is pointing to the first line of code for the Pivot Table, yet I ran that PT macro and it worked perfectly- so I don’t know why that would be an issue. At first, VBA highlighted this as the issue:

```
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheet(dataname, Version:=6)
```

Then, VBA highlighted the first line of code for the Pivot Table- so now I’m really confused. It also might be helpful to note that I am working in one file and one sheet (that contains the table I’m trying to create a Pivot Table and Power Chart out of). I’m not a VBA coder so any insight would be greatly appreciated! The full code I have is below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim dataname As String
    Dim newsheet As String
    dataname = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    Range("UPData[#All]").Select
    Sheets.Add
    newsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                      dataname, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=newsheet & "!R3C1", _
                                      TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets(newsheet).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= _
                              ActiveWorkbook.Sheet(dataname, Version:=6)
    Range("B4").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("FP Patron Code")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Age")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                                                        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("Bal Due"), "Sum of Bal Due", xlSum
    Range("B5").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Sum of Bal Due")
        .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -465.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 176.25
    Range("H18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FP Patron Code Contact List"
    Range("H18").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    Range("H19").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
End Sub
```

For the final results I would like for the Pivot Table and Power Chart to run smoothly with the macro. Thanks guys!